# Disk Was Part of RAID, Now Won't Even "Initialize" In Windows

Tags: windows, raid, hard-drive, raid-0

I had a RAID-0 with two 2TB disks. I moved all useful data off of them, but did not break the "RAIDness" on the system it was operating on. Now, I have moved one of them to another machine, but the disk seems unusable.

Windows' disk management shows it as a 4TB "Intel Raid 0" disk, and says that I must "initialize" it before using it. But the initialization fails with a "CRC Error".

Using "diskpart", I can bring the disk offline, but nothing more. It too shows it as a 4TB disk with no partitions.

Intel Rapid Storage Technology tool doesn't even list the disk in question.

On the current machine, I don't have hardware RAID turned on in the UEFI. Does it matter? (If I turn that on, my Windows won't boot anymore.)

Is there a way to "break" the RAID? I should emphasize again that there is no useful data on the disk. I just prefer not to throw out a perfectly good disk.

P.S. I neither have access to the other half of the original RAID, nor the machine that the array was created on.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I ended up enabling RAID mode in the UEFI settings (I guess I shouldn't call it BIOS anymore,) and although the system wouldn't boot anymore, I had access to the Intel RAID controller settings (Ctrl+I on my machine,) and removed the RAID volume from there. Then I reverted the RAID setting to AHCI, and everything is fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following on windows.

Open CMD as admin.

```
diskpart
list disk
select disk 2 (Where 2 is the disk that you want to wipe)
clean (This can take a while)
```

Now windows disk management should see it as a empty disk, that you can initiate there.

Comment: Thanks for this. I don't know whether it would have worked for me, since I solved it another way, and that particular situation is **hard** to duplicate. But I will certainly remember the `clean` command the next time I put myself into this... "situation".